# How To store form data in cookies OctoberCMS

Tags: cookies, octobercms

I have been searching through the docs and can't seem to find an example of how to store cookies. I have a simple form with two inputs that I would like to store the values of when the user returns to the website after a selected amount of time. While the docs are thorough I can seem to find working example of certain thing as in Laravel. Loving this CMS so far, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Cookie` service facade to read and write cookies.

https://octobercms.com/docs/services/request-input#cookies

Retrieving a cookie value

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

Queue the cookie with the next page response

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that in the documentaion I'm just not sure where to add the code, or how to use a specific facade. Sorry if its a silly question, just eager to learn. Thanks!